# C++ array of objects with const initializer list

Tags: c++

I have some code like this:

```
class MyObject {
  private:
    int x;
  public:
    MyObject(int x) : x(x) {}
};
```

I want to initialize 5 `MyObject` instances. I know I can do this with g++ 8.3.0.

```
MyObject obj_array[5]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

However, I'm unable to do this:

```
const int myInts[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
MyObject obj_array[5](myInts);
```

Is there any way to make the second initialization method (initializing array of objects with initialization list constructors using const integer array) work? The rub is that we have a special compiler framework that doesn't allow dynamic memory or most STL datatypes such as `vector`.

Comment: Just use `std::array` (or `boost::array`, or your own variant). It doesn't allocate anything dynamically. Do you require *exactly* the initialization syntax that you are asking for?

Comment: Can you use `std::array`'s?  Also, what language standard can you use (03,11,14,17)?

Comment: `std::array` also not allowed. The (highly proprietary) compiler allows a subset of C++11, but no dynamic memory, no recursion, no STL datatypes, no transcendental functions, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're doing ugly solutions, here's one with scalability:

```
#define LIST { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }
const int myInts[] = LIST;
MyObject obj_array[] = LIST;
#undef LIST
```

Comment: This is actually a little better than @selbie's original solution. Thanks for the code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty, but this seems to work:

```
const int myInts[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
MyObject obj_array[5] = {myInts[0], myInts[1], myInts[2], myInts[3], myInts[4]};
```

Comment: Ah, this is great! This is pretty close to what I was looking for.

Comment: The repetition could be hidden in a Boost.Preprocessor trick, too.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, since when a raw array type is initialized with fewer than its count of expressions, objects get default-initialized.

But one thing you could do would be to create your own array-like class template:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

template <std::size_t N>
class MyObjectArray
{
public:
    using array_type = MyObject[N];
    template <typename T, typename Enable =
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, int>>>
    MyObjectArray(T (&arr)[N]);

    template <typename T = int, typename Enable =
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, int>>>
    MyObjectArray(std::initializer_list<T> il);

    template <typename InputIter, typename Enable =
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<
            typename std::iterator_traits<InputIter>::reference, int>>>
    MyObjectArray(InputIter start, InputIter end);

    operator array_type& () noexcept { return m_array; }
    operator const array_type& () const noexcept { return m_array; }

private:
    template <std::size_t... I, typename InputIter>
    MyObjectArray(std::index_sequence<I...>, InputIter iter)
        : m_array{ (static_cast<void>(I), *iter++) ... } {}

    static std::make_index_sequence<N> check_count(std::size_t n) {
        if (n != N)
            throw std::invalid_argument(
                "Incorrect number of elements initializing MyObjectArray");
        // Or if exceptions not supported, some other error reporting
        // mechanism and abort.
        return {};
    }

    MyObject m_array[N];
};

template <std::size_t N>
template <typename T, typename Enable>
MyObjectArray<N>::MyObjectArray(T (&arr)[N])
    : MyObjectArray(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, arr) {}

template <std::size_t N>
template <typename T, typename Enable>
MyObjectArray<N>::MyObjectArray(std::initializer_list<T> il)
    : MyObjectArray(check_count(il.size()), il.begin()) {}

template <std::size_t N>
template <typename InputIter, typename Enable>
MyObjectArray<N>::MyObjectArray(InputIter start, InputIter end)
    : MyObjectArray(check_count(std::distance(start, end)), start) {}
```

This can be used like:

```
int main()
{
    const int myInts[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    MyObjectArray obj_array(myInts);

    MyObjectArray<5> a2 = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
}
```

See the [working code on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b831ffc96cc790d6).